# Left and Right side container border not the same

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have been working on my business website, over the past week, and yesterday i got into a problem, that i can not find a solution for.

http://multisupport.dk/

As you can see, the left border is difference than the right border, i basicly want the borders, to look the same in both sides ( left & right ).

I have tried everything that i possibly could think of, i have tried to give paddings on the right side, to "check" if the border was hiding behind another container.

I also tried to make border, on all content containers, but that didn't work either.

[image]

A wiseman once said, a picture says more than a 1000 words, so here is a picture that explains pretty good what i would apreciate, to get some help with :)

Comment: your code would be helpful :)

Comment: Actually having a look to your link(site), looks fine, no issues there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is because of your DOM structure:

```
<body>
    <div class="container second">
        <div class="container">
...
```

As you note you have two nested `container`s. If you look at the css for the container you see that it has the property `width: 1200px`, which includes any potential borders. As the outer `div` has a border of `1px`, that means that the inner `div` will have 2 less pixels to work with and the true size should be `1198px`.

To solve the problem you could change the static width, but I would suggest against nesting `container`s, as I do not reckon that is its purpose.

Edit: To make it work with all different display-sizes you could add:

```
@media (min-width:768px) {
    .second {
        width: 752px;
    }
}

@media (min-width:992px) {
    .second {
        width: 972px;
    }
}

@media (min-width:1200px) {
    .second {
        width: 1202px;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, however, changing the width to 1198px doesn't change the border, it stil looks differently on the right side, compared to left side.

What the purpose of the outer container was, is to function as a 'wrapper' 

If you have a suggestion how to do that better, than what i have done, i would really apreciate the help :)

Comment: You have to change the width specifically to the outer div.  `<div class="container" style="width: 1198px">` for the inner div works on my browsers.

Comment: The other possibility is to just simply one of the `container`, as it is redundant I would say.

Comment: Fixing the width in the div, fixed the problem as you said, thanks alot , if u write an answer, ill give you credit :)

Comment: good. from bootstrap's site: "Containers: Bootstrap requires a containing element to wrap site contents and house our grid system. You may choose one of two containers to use in your projects. Note that, due to padding and more, neither container is nestable."

Answer (score 1):

add this width to the first div:

```
<body id="page-top">
    <div class="container second" style="width: 972px;">
```

i haven't figured out the cause exactly but bootstrap's container is:

```
.container {
    width: 970px;
}
```

and the nested containers (or edges) are affected.

Comment: I have described the reason in my answer. We have different `width`s, but that is because of the bootstrap `@media` queries (e.i. they define a container width for 3 different sizes: small, medium, and large devices)